# Creating an object from the show action of another object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a fairly typical blog application with posts and comments.

Each comment belongs to one post
A post can have many comments.

Basically I want to add a form for comments to the show action for posts, without having post_id under attr_accessible in the comment model.

In my posts controller I have:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @poster = "#{current_user.name} #{current_user.surname} (#{current_user.email})"
    @comment = @post.comments.build( poster: @poster )
  end
```

I'm not entirely sure what I should be doing in the comments controller (I'm not confident that the code above is right either if I'm honest). At the moment I have:

```
 def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:post])
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: "Comment posted"
  else
    redirect_to @post, error: "Error!"
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
  resources :comments

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

and finally the form:

```
<%= form_for @post.comments.build do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :content, "WRITE COMMENT" %>
        <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 3 %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: @post.id %>
        <%= f.submit "Post" %>
    <% end %>
```

The problem here is that I have no way of passing my post_id from the show action of the posts controller to the create action of the comments controller. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your posts controller looks fine... but assuming your routes looks like

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

then your CommentsController#create should/could look like:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: "Comment posted"
  else
    redirect_to @post, error: "Error!"
  end
end
```

And your form:

```
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :poster, value: @poster %>
    <%= f.label :content, "WRITE COMMENT" %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 3 %>
    <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @YuriyGoldshtrakh I am fast like ninja!

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, but at the moment it tells me that it can't find the post_id in the create action? I'll stick my routes and view up in case that's the issue...

Comment: Ok, so I accepted this a little pre-maturely sorry. I've copied your form word for word and now it doesn't return any errors from the controller, but it doesn't seem to save any comments either.

Comment: change to save! and see what fails

Comment: Thank you for all the help, when I use save! It says content can't be blank and poster can't be blank. This is strange as they're both specified in hidden fields?

Comment: `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"wdlB08IAsIwq4NQq2TgVkI2JdToLLKZ5eto+IdI+Glc=",
 "comment"=>{"post_id"=>"3",
 "poster"=>"Sample user (sample@gmail.com)",
 "content"=>"dfadsa"},
 "commit"=>"Post",
 "post_id"=>"3"}` However the parameters seem to be passing correctly?

Comment: Looks like your model has attr_protected (or doesn't have attr_acessible set).

Comment: This line is included in my comments model:

  attr_accessible :content, :poster

And my posts:

attr_accessible :content, :subject

Shouldn't that have worked in that case?

Comment: There was a mistake in my code... should be `@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])`

Comment: I've changed it to that but now it's returning a mass-assignment error with regards to post id, despite the fact that it's using a build method. I've just changed the post id to be accessible for now as I think I've spent a bit too much time wrestling with this one problem. Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The URL for your show post should be like `post/show/(:id)`.
Now, in the comment form, you can place a hidden field, with value of `params[:id]`.

```
hidden_field(:post_id, :value => params[:id])
```

When you submit your form, you can get the value of post_id using the hidden field.

```
def create
        @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
        @comment.post_id = params[:post_id]

        if @comment.save
          flash[:notice] = 'Comment posted.'
          redirect_to post_path(@comment.post_id)
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Error!"
          redirect_to post_path(@comment.post_id)
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your post model has_many comments and comment belongs_to post

than you in your routes file you can do something like this

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

this will give you a url schem such as

/posts/:post_id/comments , allowing you to always have post_id of the comment parrent